# SoapUI Virts not showing requests from REST calls

Tags: c#, json, rest, dotnet-httpclient

I have a Virt created based off of a REST service. When I make calls into the virt using HttpClient, the request doesn't show the JSON in the Transaction Log. However, if I call that virt from within SoapUI, it shows the request. I assume this must be an issue with my HttpClient setup.

This is my HttpClient setup and Json call:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(requestUri, orderRequest);
```

Can't really find anything with a search on this.

Comment: from your code I see that you are not awaiting the async call ... that could be the problem.

Comment: I get the virt response that I am expecting. Also, I have code that awaits it in another area. The problem is that my virt Transaction log doesn't show the request.